# How to convert string to date ignoring zone part?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

Because of the way dates are stored I need to get them exact as stored but zone make me trouble.

```
moment("2020-10-28T08:41:00.000Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm") // Result: 2020-10-28 09:41
```

But I need to get value of this string date without zone, so I cut of 000Z part:

```
moment("2020-10-28T08:41:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm") // Result: 2020-10-28 08:41
```

And that is the real value I need.
What I am trying to get is some more elegant way to do this conversion from string to date without making function to `cutOffZone()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [moment.utc()](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) constructor, it will use utc mode, so the time will not be converted to local time. From the moment documentation:

> moment.utc(...) is utc mode. Ambiguous input is assumed to be UTC. Unambiguous input is adjusted to UTC.

```js
// Use moment.utc() constructor...
const dt = new moment.utc("2020-10-28T08:41:00.000Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
console.log(dt)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: More to the point is that formatted output will be UTC. If the timestamp contains an offset, it will be used in generating the underlying date so the output date and time will be different if the offset isn't +0. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need string manipulation:

```
"2020-10-28T08:41:00.000Z".split(".")[0]
```

Comment: No actually I thought to make this somehow with date and format without string manipulation. Only if no other way.